Elastic search how to executed nested query
In an index, we store information for example student and their department information.
Looking for query to get all the students  belonging to the same department as a given student name passed in the search clause.
In normal RDBMS, this can be achieved
SELECT
    *
FROM
    student_dept
WHERE
    dept_name in(
        SELECT
            dept_name FROM student_dept
        WHERE
            student_name = 'John')

Do we have an option to achieve similar result in ES?
Note: The search and nested query as well happens on the same index.
Expecting a Elastic search query that can provide the needed result

Could you please share your Schema or Mapping? This would help to provide better understanding of your data structure.

Answer #1. Aggregations, top_hits, and bucket_selector
You could use aggregation with two nested aggregations and sort buckets by one of them
I use mapping
PUT /students_from_depts
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "student_name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "to_keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "dept_name": {
                "type": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}

and sample documents
PUT /students_from_depts/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"student_name":"John","dept_name":"Economics"}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"student_name":"Peter","dept_name":"Economics"}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"student_name":"Ann","dept_name":"Economics"}
{"create":{"_id":4}}
{"student_name":"John","dept_name":"Art"}
{"create":{"_id":5}}
{"student_name":"Margaux","dept_name":"Art"}
{"create":{"_id":6}}
{"student_name":"Justin","dept_name":"Computer Sciences"}
{"create":{"_id":7}}
{"student_name":"Mary","dept_name":"Computer Sciences"}

Aggregation query has two nested aggregations. student_names lists student names from a department. by_student_name filters by student name. The include parameter stores a student name for searching. Change it if you need. by_student_name_bucket_count_filter filters departments with a student named John
GET /students_from_depts/_search?filter_path=aggregations.by_dept_name.buckets.key,aggregations.by_dept_name.buckets.student_names.hits.hits._source
{
    "aggs": {
        "by_dept_name": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "dept_name"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "student_names": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 10
                    }
                },
                "by_student_name": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "student_name.to_keyword",
                        "include": "John"
                    }
                },
                "by_student_name_bucket_count_filter": {
                    "bucket_selector": {
                        "buckets_path": {
                            "student_name_bucket_count": "by_student_name._bucket_count"
                        },
                        "script": "params.student_name_bucket_count > 0"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Response
{
    "aggregations" : {
        "by_dept_name" : {
            "buckets" : [
                {
                    "key" : "Economics",
                    "student_names" : {
                        "hits" : {
                            "hits" : [
                                {
                                    "_source" : {
                                        "student_name" : "John",
                                        "dept_name" : "Economics"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "_source" : {
                                        "student_name" : "Peter",
                                        "dept_name" : "Economics"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "_source" : {
                                        "student_name" : "Ann",
                                        "dept_name" : "Economics"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key" : "Art",
                    "student_names" : {
                        "hits" : {
                            "hits" : [
                                {
                                    "_source" : {
                                        "student_name" : "John",
                                        "dept_name" : "Art"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "_source" : {
                                        "student_name" : "Margaux",
                                        "dept_name" : "Art"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}


Answer #2. Transform with the scripted_metric Aggregation
You could transform to create an subsidiary index with dept names and their students as well
I use the same mapping and documents (see Answer #1)
Create a transform to generate the depts_and_students index by a query. The query contains scripted_metric for collecting student names
PUT _transform/students_to_depts
{
    "source": {
        "index": "students_from_depts"
    },
    "dest": {
        "index": "depts_and_students"
    },
    "pivot": {
        "group_by": {
            "dept_name": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "dept_name"
                }
            }
        },
        "aggregations": {
            "student_names": {
                "scripted_metric" : {
                    "init_script" : """
                        state.list = new LinkedList();
                    """,
                    "map_script": """
                        String studentName = doc['student_name.to_keyword'].value;
                        state.list.add(studentName);
                    """,
                    "combine_script": "return state.list",
                    "reduce_script" : """
                        List totalStudentNames = new LinkedList();
                        for (list in states) {
                            totalStudentNames.addAll(list);
                        }
                        return totalStudentNames;
                    """
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

and start it
POST _transform/students_to_depts/_start

Search for John in the generated index
GET /depts_and_students/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "student_names.keyword": {
                "value": "John"
            }
        }
    }
}

Response
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_source" : {
                    "student_names" : [
                        "John",
                        "Margaux"
                    ],
                    "dept_name" : "Art"
                }
            },
            {
                "_source" : {
                    "student_names" : [
                        "John",
                        "Peter",
                        "Ann"
                    ],
                    "dept_name" : "Economics"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

You should synchronize original and generated indices regularly
